# How to use useEffect() correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-hooks

I want to change style by scrolling.

This code isn't working correctly
.
When I rolling up and down too many times and too fast, then the browser is going to freeze, crash.

I think I used `useEffect()` wrong. How can I solve this issue.

```
const ArticleItem = ({title, content, active, chapter, program, id, scrollPos}) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const client = useApolloClient();

  useEffect(() => {
    if(ref.current.offsetTop <= (scrollPos + 200)) {
      client.writeData({data: {
        curChapter: chapter.num,
        curArticle: id,
        curProgram: program.name
      }});
    }
  });

  if(active === false)
    return ( // Inactive Article
      <div className='section-item' ref={ref}>
        <h2>{title.toUpperCase()}</h2>
        <ReactMarkdown source={content} />
        <br />
      </div>
    )
  return (  // Active Article
    <div className='section-item active' ref={ref}>
      <h2>{title.toUpperCase()}</h2>
      <ReactMarkdown source={content} />
      <br />
    </div>
  )
}
```

As a Result, I faced this warning.

> Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

I think this is the reason of issue?!

Comment: You need to include the dependency array for `useEffect` also. In this way it is running infinitely. Probably you want to include `scrollPos` into that.

Comment: @norbitrial is correct, do: `useEffect(() => {}, [dependency]` now the function will only run if the dependency value changed. You probably also want to denounce, meaning only update if it didn't change for a certain amount of time

Comment: @Elias think you meant "debounce"

Comment: Oh yes... excuse me

Answer (score 3):

Based on my comment above, you need to include the dependency array for `useEffect` also. In the current way it is running infinitely. Probably you want to include `scrollPos` into that thus it would only triggered once `scrollPos` is changing.

Try the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(ref.current.offsetTop <= (scrollPos + 200)) {
      client.writeData({data: {
        curChapter: chapter.num,
        curArticle: id,
        curProgram: program.name
      }});
    }
}, [scrollPos]);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Looks like a fix but debounce would be better with it as https://stackoverflow.com/users/10315665/elias said

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is triggered all the time you can use the `scroll` event listener and make your changes when this event is triggered.

```
const [scrollItem, setScrollItem] = useState(null);

const handleScroll() {
  if(scrollItem) {
     // logic goes here
  }
}

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  };
}, []); // initialize event only once

return (
   <div ref={setScrollItem}>
      ...
   </div>
);
```

**EDIT**

Avoid that solution, @norbitrial is right

Comment: well, you're adding an event listener for `scroll` he seems to be recieving it from the props.

Comment: hmm indeed, I didn't see that.

Comment: Well, thing is... this is actually more performant, but not what he asked for... it's probably quite inefficient to render a component every time someone scrolls